# Can I use rack-test for deployment tests?

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra, rack, rack-test

I've built a simple api in `Sinatra`, with the purpose of setting up a deployment pipeline using `Docker`. I'm at a stage where I could easily switch `Sinatra` for something else and there's currently one reason why I might do so.

I once wrote an api using `Express` and it was trivial to reuse the tests to test a deployment:

```
# Testing the code
chai.request(app)
  .get('/')

# Testing a deployment
chai.request('http://localhost:8080')
  .get('/')
```

Examples from: https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#integration-testing

Now I am wondering if I can accomplish the same with `rack-test` and `Sinatra`. Simply sending a URL, instead of the app, crashes. So is there an easy way to accomplish this? I suppose I could write a testing framework on top of `rack-test`, but I'm not sure it's worth it, even though I do prefer `Ruby` over `Javascript` and `Sinatra` over `Express`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that I should be able to write a rack app that forwards all requests to the environment I want to run deployment tests against. So I went to Google and found a gem that does just that: [`rack-proxy`](https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy)

Here's how to write a simple rack app that redirects requests to your server:

```
require 'rack/proxy'

class Foo < Rack::Proxy
  def rewrite_env(env)
    env["HTTP_HOST"] = "api.example.com"
    env
  end
end
```

Then I ran my tests against `Foo.new` they succeeded. I checked the logs of that environment and I can confirm that my tests were in fact running against that environment.

`Foo` may not be the best name for such a proxy and you may not want the host name hardcoded, but I'm sure you can figure out how to make this work in your project if you need it.